# Why do examples for the scipy function `find_peaks` always return an `_` as well as `peaks`?

Tags: python, scipy

Whenever I look at [examples](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html) for the `find_peaks` function, it always shows it used like the following

```
peaks, _ = find_peaks(x, height=0)
```

what is that `_` for? I never see it used in any of the examples.

Comment: According to the docs it returns 2 items. `_` is a valid variable name.  In the examples they don't display or use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is explained and kind of used in your link. The last example and also the documentation itself say that `find_peaks` returns a dictionary of properties of the found peaks.
`_` is used if the return value can be discarded. That way multiple return values are still unpacked. If you would write instead:

```
peaks = find_peaks(x, height=0)
```

the peaks would need to be accessed by peaks[0], since peaks[1] now contains the returned dictionary.